# Mercurial Pushing closed branches

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to figure out why Mercurial thinks I'm trying to create a new remote branch in this situation:

[alt text http://a.yfrog.com/img716/8421/9vz.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img716/8421/9vz.png)

Is it just trying to inform me that the branch will show up in the meta-data as a closed branch?

I'm on Mercurial v1.6.1023

**Edit**: the only branch on the remote repository is named "default"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `hg push` is going to push all changesets in your local repository that are not in the remote repository.  If you have some changes on a local branch (`Environment_Switching` in your case) -- even a closed branch --  they'll go too *unless* you explicitly exclude them using `hg push -b default` (assuming you haven't merged that branch back onto `default`).

To answer your question, it's just a warning that you're creating a new remote branch.

EDIT: `hg push -r default` and `hg push -b default` are equivalent.  From the output for `hg help revs`:

> Mercurial supports several ways to specify individual revisions. ...*text removed for brevity*... A branch name denotes the tipmost revision of that branch.

Pushing the tipmost revision of a branch will also push its ancestors, which are the rest of the changesets on the branch.

Comment: Your explanation does clarify what the message is telling me.  However, I did try "hg push -b default" and I still got the message that I was going to push new branch(es).  

I did not try @Ry4an's suggestion of "hg push -r default", but I'm guessing they are equivalent.

Comment: It sounds like you merged the `Environment_Switching` branch back onto default already.  In that case, you're either going to have to (a) push that branch to the remote repository (use the `--new-branch` option to `hg push`), or (b) use a combination of `hg clone`, `hg export` and `hg import` to create a local repository without the changes, then push from there, or (c) do some trickery with the Transplant extension to move the changes onto `default` before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misunderstood the question. The following is how you get multiple heads in one branch.

---

Normally a new head is created if you have a different base than the remote.
I've seen this in the following workflow:
R1 User A commits and pushes
R1 User B pulls
R2 User A commits and pushes
R? User B commits and pushes

Mercurial will decide that the push of User B is based on R1, while the server is on R2, so it will accept the changes of User B only on a different branch.
To prevent this, commit the changes of User B locally, then perform a `hg pull`, followed by a `hg merge` and merge your changes with the remote changes.
Than you can push your changes to the remote server.

Comment: What you describe are different heads on one branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even your closed branches are pushed when you do a `hg push`.  If you want to push just default you can do a `hg push -r default` that then you won't see that message.